# Bad Report Format odoo 8

Tags: format, report, odoo, openerp-8

Whenever i print any report it doesn't come with defined format.
Here i have attached report screen.

[image: Bad Form]

Actual format is:
[image: Proper Format]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you find any solution to this problem?

Comment: @Pooja: Facing the same issue. Did you find any solution for that?

Comment: Hi,The issue was I restored db and current port is different than previous port no. Go to system parameters and check Report URL. Change port if necessary. Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Your report is missing the header and footer sections.
This is a known issue with older versions of `wkhtmltopdf`. It should be at least version 0.12.0.

The current version can be checked with:

```
$ wkhtmltopdf --version
wkhtmltopdf 0.12.1 (with patched qt)
```

Check the latest version for your platform at http://wkhtmltopdf.org/downloads.html and install it.

For example, to install current 0.12.1 64 bits:

```
$ sudo apt-get remove --purge wkhtmltopdf 
$ wget http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/wkhtmltopdf/0.12.1/wkhtmltox-0.12.1_linux-trusty-amd64.deb
$ sudo dpkg -i wkhtmltox-0.12.1_linux-trusty-amd64.deb
```

Answer (score 0):

After install wkhtmltopdf 0.12.0 still header missing ?

There is small configuration you can try this [Report formatting not working in Odoo 8 Qweb Reports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30395900/report-formatting-not-working-in-odoo-8-qweb-reports/32715905#32715905)