# Report formatting not working in Odoo 8 Qweb Reports

Tags: report, wkhtmltopdf, odoo, odoo-8, qweb

All the default reports and the new reports that I am generating are being printed towards the left of the page. This only happens when the report is generated in PDF format. In HTML format the report is displayed fine. I did some research and found that downgrading the wkhtmltox to version 0.21.1 would solve this problem. I did that, but the problem still persists.

Comment: Does it solve your problem or not ??

Comment: I tried it. Does not solve the problem.

Comment: can u post your error over hear ..??

Answer (score 6):

There is one small configuration 
Go to settings --> Technical --> Parameters --> System Parameters -->

Click on Create and type

[image]

Done

Answer (score 1):

You can try with completely un install and install again it again **wkhtmlttopdf 0.12.X** python library and try to print that report again..

I hope this should helpful for you ..:)

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu 14.04, open the terminal and type:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ecometrica/servers
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install wkhtmltopdf
```

In Ubuntu 12.04, open the terminal and type:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:pov/wkhtmltopdf
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install wkhtmltopdf
```

If That Was Not Working Then Following This Step

1) Download wkhtmltopdf version from wkhtmltopdf.org depend on your system arch (32 or 64 bit)

```
 wget http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/wkhtmltopdf/0.12.1/wkhtmltox-0.12.1_linux-trusty-amd64.deb
```

2) Install the package using commnad :

```
sudo dpkg -i wkhtmltox-0.12.1_linux-trusty-amd64.deb
```

3) Copy binary or wkhtmltopdf to /usr/bin location from ./usr/local/bin use command

```
sudo cp /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf /usr/bin/
```

4) Restart Odoo server and try once again.